# Unity and Apple TV Remote control sensitivity

Tags: unity, control, apple-tv

I'm developing a game for Apple TV and I'm responding to the swipe gesture using

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Joystick1Button4)){
   DoSomething();
}
```

But the problem is that this is too sensitive, and triggers when the player didn't intentionally swipe. Is there any way to set the sensitivity?